# Candle wax on the porthole?

Tags: seaquest

SeaQuest DSV *Knight of Shadows* (time stamp 18:00) Chief Engineer Hitchcock says to that she's found a porthole sealed with candle wax.

Is this even possible on a sunken ship? Wouldn't candle wax be unable to hold that kind of pressure back for very long?

Comment: If it's just being used to seal the cracks, it might work.  In that case, the porthole door is still holding most of the pressure, and the wax is just stopping whatever trickling leaks might get in through the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Notably the room isn't flooded with external water, it's been deliberately filled with water pumped through the ventilation system and then sealed. That being the case, the main source of pressure isn't the hundreds of feet of water above the ship pressing down, but only the water in the room itself trying to escape, and then only the pressure of the water at and above the level of the window.

The room looks to be about 10' x 10' and the water above the line is about five foot deep. That being the case, then there's zero chance that the wax is holding back the full 250 psi, but it could certainly be holding back micro-leaks caused by the porthole not sitting entirely flush to the other side of the door. That would also explain why it's only waxed at the bottom of the porthole (where excess water was dripping in), not all the way around.

[image]